# Removing default classes from wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress

For any plugin installed for wordpress, how can I remove default classes, ids and wrappers. Is there any snippet to be included in functions.php? Or some other way to get rid off the default markup?

Comment: Go to plugin file and remove the classes manually? Or target those elements with jquery and remove the classes with `.removeClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by editing the plugins' files, and there is no other way to do that.

The fact is you should avoid editing plugins that way, as it can simply break them. If you think that a class, id or anything else is optional, you can still contact the plugin's author (it's possible from WordPress.org). If it is really optional, maybe they will update their plugin to make it optional.